# Detect method by self.sender() in Python

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

is there a way to detect which method has run other method similarly as you detect object with self.sender()?

For example I have a method A that enables all the checkboxes. On one page I have 10 on other 15. Depending on the method B or C that will call method A, I can define two scenarios in method A, rather than to copy the code.

Comment: No need to make things overcomplicated. Add an argument in A that defines the number of checkboxes to check. Then methods B and C can simply be written as wrappers of method A that pass different values of the argument.

Comment: OK, I know for approach with arguments. Also, the names of the checkboxes are different etc. But is there a such possibility, to find out which method triggered other method?

Comment: I've added my answer that covers the thing you want. Nevertheless, I wouldn't recommend you to use this approach for anything serious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. It utilizes the `inspect` module

```
import inspect

def echo():
    """Returns the name of a function that called it"""
    return inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe(), 2)[1][3]

def caller():
    return echo()

print(caller(), caller.func_name)
```

Output:

```
('caller', 'caller')
```